# How would I do this - Animate Menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

This is probably against the rules to ask something straight off but I am at the end of my tether!

Please see these images.

[image: Without Sub- Menu]

[image: With Sub-menu]

I need to animate the sub-menu coming down when about is clicked. When ABOUT is clicked I need the sub-menu to animate down and then across.

What Jquery can I use for this?

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thank You

Comment: Can you provide the html that you're using for the menu items?

Comment: how about [`animating`](http://api.jquery.com/animate)  the `width` and `height` properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Yk8bR/1/

I used hover, instead of click, but you can change that.

```
$('#menu ul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').show(400);
},
function(){
    $(this).find('ul').hide(0);
});
```

HTML (don't forget to anchors)

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About
        <ul>
            <li>The Company</li>
            <li>The Team</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Services</li>
</ul>
```

You'll see basic CSS in demo, I can't bother with that.

Comment: Thank you webarto! That's exactly what I want. However is there anyway to make the other submenu items (The Team) show smoother? The Company seems to work ok but The Team seems to just show on screen without a fade

Comment: Yeah, sure, I don't like .show .hide either, you can use .fadeIn and .fadeOut, here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Yk8bR/9/ ... you can use pretty much any effect.. http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Answer (score 1):

This is just psuedo code since there's no html to work with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.menu-container-selector').children('ul').children('li').click(function() {
      if ($(this).find('ul.sub-menu-ul').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('ul.sub-menu-ul').animate({'opacity':'1','top':'30px','left':'100px'});
    }
});
```

});

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBef7/).